# How to find the location of the items I created in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, finder

I created music as .wav files using a program called Mackie Traction. I then used iTunes to convert them to .mp3 files.

How can I attach these files to an email to export them to MySpace or other similar sites?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select track in iTunes
2. Right-click -> Show/Reveal in Finder
3. Drag files from Finder window into new mail message

Alternatively (if dragging directly in step 3 doesn't work) you can click the Attachment icon in the new mail message, navigate to the folder opened in step 2 (or just drag the MP3 from the folder window into the Open dialog) and attach the file directly.

Comment: Hi Have tried this and the file just bounces back into finder .

Comment: Did you create a new mail message first? Sometimes you have to drag it into the mail window twice or wait a second til a green plus sign is displayed at the mouse cursor.

Comment: tried again on a new email and it wont stick ??

Comment: I've extended the answer already, just attach the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the control key and click on one of the songs you converted in iTunes. On the context menu that appears, one of the options is **Show in Finder**. Select that option.

A Finder window will open that reveals your file. You can then attach it to an e-mail or upload it to a website just like any other file.

If you have Apple Mail configured to work with your email account, the procedure is simple: drag the file to the Apple Mail icon on the Dock, and drop it. This will create a new mail message with your file as an attachment.